# Not understanding <C-o> in :imap <F5> <C-o>:setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<CR>

Tags: vim

[This](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_spellcheck_with_function_keys) allows me to toggle spellcheck in Vim by hitting F5 when I am in Insert mode.

```
imap <F5> <C-o>:setlocal spell! spelllang=en_us<CR>
```

But I don't understand what `<C-o>` part is doing. Do I need it?

Comment: What about `:help i_ctrl-o`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ctrl-O in insert mode allows you to leave insert mode for one command. That way, that colon command is executed instead of inserted.